# Hosting wcf application on server

Tags: c#, wcf

I just started learning WCF and I have managed to create a simple wcf console application that allows me to enter text in the client console, have that text passed to the server and then returned back to the client. What I have done is similar to the code in this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14493/WCF-Basic-Client-Server.

Now the problem is that the address of the endpoint is "net.tcp://localhost:9000/ABCD". While I have created the host application (also a console program) on my desktop, I actually want it to be on a server with a URL. What I did was to change "net.tcp://localhost:9000/ABCD" to "net.tcp://urlofserver:9000/ABCD", build the solution and then copy the resulting exe and dll files in the bin folder of visual studio onto a random folder in the server. When I finally ran the console host program on the server, it threw an error.

Sorry if my approach seems a bit naive because I just started learning c#. What should I do to make the program run properly?

- I forgot to mention that my initial success was because my server was localhost and not a real "server".

  ```
  using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
              typeof(WcfServiceLibrary.WcfService)))
      {
          host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(
              WcfServiceLibrary.IWcfService),
              new NetTcpBinding(),
              "net.tcp://localhost:9000/MyWcfEndPoint");

          host.Open();
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
  ```

Comment: Did you run the EXE file on the server?  Does the server have a firewall?  Can you telnet over port 9000 from the client to the server?  Just to be clear, both the client and the server are EXE files?  You likely need to configure both with the new endpoint.

Comment: also, what kind of error did it throw?

Comment: post your Config, and Hosting Code...looks similar like.... m_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(FirstWcfService.Service));
            m_serviceHost.Open();

Comment: Yes, I ran the exe file on the server and both the client and server files are exe files. I don't think the server has a firewall.

Comment: When I ran the server exe, the console threw a whole bunch of code and before I could read any of it, the console froze and closed by itself.

Comment: You should add some try/catches and logging so you can see the actual error messages you are getting.